# Inserting a row in mysql database it is showing rows twice

Tags: java, mysql, spring

The code is in corejava,spring,mysql while executing the controller class output is
   getting 1 correctly,
   but i inserted one row but in mysql database two rows inserted it is main problem,if any
   problem in below code ,please help to if we insert one row it has to show only one row
   in mysql database.

in IOC contain

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
 <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
 <property   name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Springjdbc"></property>
 <property name="username" value="root"></property>
 <property name="password" value="ashok"></property>
 </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
   </bean>

<bean id="custDao" class="com.pw.spring.dao.CustomerDao">
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
</bean>
```

in dao class

```
     package com.pw.spring.dao;

     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
     import java.sql.ResultSet;
     import java.sql.SQLException;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Map;
     import java.util.Set;

     import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream;

     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter;
     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter;
     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
     import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;

     import com.mysql.jdbc.Blob;
     import com.pw.spring.dto.B1;
     import com.pw.spring.dto.CustomerDto;

     public class CustomerDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements ICustomerDao {
     @Override
     public int blobinsert() {
    int in = 0;
    String s1 = "insert into a1(name,image) values (?,?);";
    in = getJdbcTemplate().update(s1, new PreparedStatementSetter() {

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement arg0) throws SQLException {

        arg0.setString(1, "shiva");
        arg0.setObject(2, b2 ());
        arg0.executeUpdate();
    }

    private Object b2() {
        File   f1 = new File("E:\\seenu\\New folder\\Luminance.jpg");
        byte z [] = new byte[(int)f1.length()];

        try
        {


        FileImageInputStream f2 = new FileImageInputStream(f1);

        f2.read(z);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return z;
    }

    });


    return in;
        }
        }
```

in controller class to  be executed

```
package com.pw.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.pw.spring.dao.CustomerDao;

public class Nutt 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");      
         CustomerDao dao =(CustomerDao) context.getBean("custDao");
         int i = dao.blobinsert();
         System.out.println(i)
    }
 }
```

table is a1 in schema springjdbc

```
create table a1 (name varchar(20),image BLOB);


output:1
```

but it is inserting rows twice in mysql database instead of one row inserting like

```
shiva blob
shiva blob
```

can help how to insert one row in mysql database in code?
Advance thanks to the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `arg0.executeUpdate();` inside `setValues`.

**You execute the insert statement twice**: both in `in = getJdbcTemplate().update(..)` and in `arg0.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 6):

Don't call `arg0.executeUpdate();` in [`setValues()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementSetter.html#setValues%28java.sql.PreparedStatement%29). This method is for **setting** values not for executing the statement.

[`JdbcTemplate.update()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter%29) will execute the statement.